# Changing 'data block' name of object from python script

Tags: python, scripting, objects, outliner, data-blocks

I am trying to change the name of the object in the data block from the python script. The operation name is: `bpy.ops.outliner.id_operation(type='RENAME')`.

*But I am not experienced on Blender and I don't know how to use that function, so can someone help me on that subject please?*

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Glad I could help. You are welcome...